# Graphical Interface software for Eclipse Database

Tags: oracle11g

I am new to Oracle database. I have downloaded Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2 and installed it on my laptop but when I open the database it opens command line. Is there any GUI software available? Please help me to get for the write one.

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle SQL Developer** is a free graphical tool for database development. With SQL Developer, you can browse database objects, run SQL statements and SQL scripts, and edit and debug PL/SQL statements.
try this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html